# Nebeans 8.2 freezing when performing certain operations on ubuntu 18

Tags: java, netbeans

Netbeans is freezing when I open a particular file, it freezes and I have to kill the process. When I debug the file the entire OS freezes and only the mouse cursor stays active. I have to press the power button to reboot. When I press CTRL + f and I try to find text inside that troubled file the netbeans freezes. What can it be? I've tried to create another file and copy the contents it didn't work. I've tried to clear and build the projects and it didn't work.

Comment: What's in this mysterious "particular file"?

Comment: Its happens only with a file. I tried to clone the project it worked normally for 30min and now it just happened. With that one file.

Comment: [1] You state _"Netbeans is freezing when I open a particular file"_, yet you also claim that _"When I press CTRL + f and I try to find text inside that troubled file the netbeans freezes"_. Those statements contradict each other, so update your question to clarify the situation. [2] You need to provide a lot more information about your problem, including version information for Java, full details about the offending file, and details of what is written to the NetBeans log. Without additional information your question is too vague, and liable to be closed.

Comment: My problem started when I performed a search in this file, it happened rarely. After some times Netbeans started freezing more often when I worked with this file. It's a swing form "dot" java file, to be more specifically. Now just opening the file freezes netbeans when NOT THE COMPUTER. But I solved the problem I cloned the project again and my problem desappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the project and clone it again! It solved my problem.